# At some FAQ pages, a paragraph is without the customary highlighting

Tags: bug

Not an urgent issue.

The two-sentence paragraph quoted below is either:

- orphaned in some way (did it previously have a link from the sidebar to its right?); or
- not highlighted as it should be

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
>   also OK to ask and answer your own question.

## Screenshot

[image]

### Possibly related

[Replying to one's own question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402/replying-to-ones-own-question#comment1302_403) commentary on comparisons with *Jeopardy!* … I wonder whether the issue with the paragraph above arose when that comparison was removed.

### Bugged

- [apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) (screenshot above)
- some other stacks.

### Not bugged

- [meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

## Test environment

Safari 6.0 (8536.25) in released Build 12A269 of OS X 10.8.

Firefox 14.0.1 on the same build of OS X.

Comment: I replicated it in my Chrome browser for Apple SE.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what browser is being used.